# How can I make JavaScript modules work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, module, internet-explorer-11, transcrypt

I have JavaScript [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) which I want to use with IE11.

In the HTML pages they are referenced like this:

```
<script type="module">
     import * as mystuff from './scripts/mystuff.js'; window.mystuff = mystuff
</script>
```

They do not work in Internet Explorer 11, but I cannot change the modules to normal scripts (because they are generated by [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/)). How can I make them work with IE? Does a polyfill or something similar for the `<script type="module">` construct exist?

Comment: it may get conflict but you can think about merge all script to single page

Comment: @hosseinsedighian  You mean using a bundler?  Can't do that: Our project is a legacy project where the JavaScript sources need to stay how they are. But I can _add_ a script which ports the module functionality to IE if that's possible.

Comment: In your previous comment, you had mentioned that you can add a script that ports the module functionality to IE. I suggest trying to use the JS code to identify the IE browser and try to load the script. If the browser is different then you can run your normal code. This approach can help to fix the issue for the IE browser. you can try to refer to this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/gk7xA/). Let us know whether suggested approach works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @Deepak-MSFT! Identifying whether I am in IE or not isn't enough: I need to _convert_ the modules somehow to scripts. I tried rollup.js so far, but was not successful, because the `document` global variable seems to be not right in the rolled-up code.

Comment: In my search result, I found [ES Module Loader Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-module-loader). You can try to check and test it may help you to load your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. IE does not understand the `type="module"` attribute.

Instead use [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to bundle your module into an old style script `mystuff_incl_ie.js` and load this with the normal script tag:

```
<script src='./scripts/mystuff_incl_ie.js'></script>
```

See also [Bundle JS with rollup and Babel for use in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407950/bundle-js-with-rollup-and-babel-for-use-in-ie11).