# Bundle JS with rollup and Babel for use in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, module, babeljs, rollupjs

I try to bundle two JavaScript modules, so that the resulting code works in IE11. For this I have setup a yarn/npm project which uses *rollup.js* for bundling and *Babel* for transpiling. Everything works fine until I add the (non-dev) dependency `core-js`.

Here the details:

### 1 Setup *before* adding *core-js*

#### JS files

- **src/main.js**
- **src/utils.js**

#### Config files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rollup_for_ie",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.24.0"
  },
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/main.js',
        format: 'iife'
    },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true
    }),
    babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**", // only transpile our source code
        babelHelpers: 'bundled'
    })
  ]
};
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: "> 0.5%, ie >= 11"
        },
        modules: false,
        spec: true,
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        forceAllTransforms: true,
        corejs: 3
      }
    ]
  ],
};
```

When I run `rollup -c` I get warnings about unresolved dependencies, but a bundled file `dist/main.js` with the (used) stuff from the *src* directory is generated. The resulting file works even in modern browsers like Chrome.  So far so good.

### Problems *after* adding *core-js*

However the bundled file is not yet IE11 ready: In IE I get errors like *Object doesn't support property or method 'getOwnPropertySymbols'*. So the polyfills from *core-js* need to be added.

For this I install *core-js* as a prod dependency. Now `rollup -c` doesn't give me warnings - but the resulting *dist/main.js* begins like

```
(function (exports) {
  'use strict';

  var $ = require('../internals/export');
.
.
.
```

which as a script can not  neither  Chrome nor IE execute! It looks like that somehow the presence of the *core-js* library throws the rollup bundler  off.

How can I fix my setup so that the resulting `dist/main.js` works as non-module script  in Chrome and IE11?

Comment: Can you tell exactly what did you do as added core-js? Did you mean by adding `corejs` option in your babel.config file?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I mean I added core-js as a prod dependency to the npm modules. I did so with `yarn add core-js`. The babel config didn't change.

Comment: Can you also share the minimal code which resulted in error? Package json & main entry point includes error

Comment: @tmhao2005 You mean the error in the browser? _After_ adding core-js I get 'require undefined'. The `rollup -c` command finishes in both cases without errors. In the first case I get warnings like "(!) Unresolved dependencies".

Comment: I got you. I’m gonna to attempt to replicate by having your code which contains the issue then try to build and see the bundled file. Does it make sense?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Cool! Thanks a lot. Will try to get this put together on Saturday.

Comment: Just mention me as you have posted your code

Comment: Hi @tmhao2005. You can download an archive of the files from [here](http://www.halloleo.net/etc/forums/rollup-issue/rollup_for_ie.zip). Thanks heaps for looking at this!!!

Comment: I did leave an answer for you anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think as you enabled the option `useBuiltIns: "usage"` which means it will append code from `corejs` into your module files which is written with `cjs` style. So you have to add this plugin `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` to convert back to `esm`, then it will work:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    commonjs(),
  ]    
};
```

Comment: Makes total sense when you explain it like this - but I would never have thought of it! Will test it with IE on Monday.

Comment: Haha :) okay let's me know the result then

Comment: Works perfectly in IE. Thanks again @tmhao2005! :-)