# Dinamically load polyfills to IE using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm currently trying to load a file `polyfills.js` when the browser is IE.
The file has a bunch of import statements for the polyfills.

```
import 'core-js/features/array/for-each';
import 'core-js/features/array/find';
import 'core-js/features/array/flat';
import 'core-js/features/array/flat-map';
import 'core-js/features/array/includes';
import 'core-js/features/array/map';
import 'core-js/features/object/assign';
import 'core-js/features/object/from-entries';
import 'core-js/features/object/entries';
import 'core-js/features/string/includes';
import 'core-js/features/url-search-params';
import 'core-js/features/object/keys';
import 'core-js/features/object/values';
import 'core-js/features/object/is-extensible';

// Fetch
import 'whatwg-fetch';

// ACCESS Patterns Polyfills
import 'utilities/element/matches';
import 'utilities/element/closest';
import 'utilities/element/remove';
import 'utilities/nodelist/foreach';

import 'modules/polyfill-replace-with';
```

I have a function that triggers when the browser is IE and it loads the compiled file `polyfills.js` via a script tag.

```
    (() => {
      if (/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document["documentMode"]) {
        let fileref = document.createElement('script');

        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", 'assets/js/polyfill.955d1924.js');

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
        console.log('IE DIE!')
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    })();
```

However, although the file is loaded via the script tag as shown in the image below:

[image]

The polyfills still seem to not be working on IE. Is there a fix?

Comment: [IE11 does not support the `import` instruction](https://caniuse.com/?search=modules) so you're going to have to at the very least first convert that swathe of imports into something that works in legacy ES5 context.

Comment: Just as Mike says, IE doesn't support `import`. You can't directly use it in IE. I think you'll need using something like Babel or Webpack to convert it to ES5 syntax to make it work in IE. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333459/how-can-i-make-javascript-modules-work-in-ie-11) to use [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to bundle your module into an old style script then load it with the normal script tag.